# How to get pub media url in .less file?

Tags: magento2, less

I have an image that i need to use in .less file, the image is located in:

```
pub/media/kool/setting/blank.gif
```

in the .less files i tried to define it like this:

@footer_bg_file:~"../kool/setting/blank.gif"

but i always got an error like this in `var/log/system.log`

```
[2020-05-04 09:05:03] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'frontend/vendor/theme/en_US/kool/setting/blank.gif' [] []
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `.lib-url('images/fallback.png');` function, this example is taken from the core in `lib/web/css/source/lib/_utilities.less`.

```
.column.left {
    .lib-url('images/fallback.png');
    background:url("@{url}") repeat-y;
}
.columns {
    .lib-url('images/fallback.png', 'Magento_Catalog');
    background:url("@{url}") repeat;
}
```

This is the function, it returns the path you specified with the base URL prepended and optionally accepts a second argument which is a module.

```
// File - lib/web/css/source/lib/_utilities.less
.lib-url(@_path) {
    @url: "@{baseDir}@{_path}";
}

.lib-url(
    @_path,
    @_module
) when not (@_module = false) and not (@_module = '') and (@urls-resolved = false) {
    @url: "@{_module}::@{_path}";
}

.lib-url(
    @_path,
    @_module
) when not (@_module = false) and not (@_module = '') and (@urls-resolved = true) {
    @url: "@{baseDir}@{_module}/@{_path}";
}
```

This function uses the @baseDir variable and optionally accepts a second argument which is a module: which is declared in `lib/web/css/source/lib/_variables.less`

```
@baseDir: "../";
```

Comment: Hi Ben, I face same issue also. How can I import app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/web/css/_sources.less file inside app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Catalog/web/css/listing.less file? I want to import in listing.less file.